# "unable to mount location "while click on my 750gb hdd linux mint

Tags: hard-drive

I cannot enter in my hard drive in mint Linux. whenever I click on my hard drive icon in computer, it shows the error message : `unable to mount location`, please help me.

Answer (score 0):

Try the following, assuming your first partition on your hard drive corresponds to /dev/sdb1

```
sudo mkdir /xyz

sudo mount /dev/sdb1 /xyz
```

The folder /xyz should be your hdd's mount point.